# Guardar campo datepicker en tabla dinámica

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo una tabla dinámica con varios campos de los cuales uno de ellos quiero que dándole click pueda cambiar la fecha y la guarde dinámicamente en php. No consigo o no sé donde poner el ajax para que guarde la fecha en un update.php y me salga la nueva fecha sin refrescar.

```
<td><div class="editableDateTxt" id="decreto_fecha-<?php echo $id_exp ?>"><?php echo $row_exp['decreto_fecha'];?></div></td>

$(document).on("click",".editableDateTxt", function () {
    var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'class':'datePicker', 'value': $(this).html()});
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.append(input);
    $(this).remove();
    input.focus();
    parent.find('.datePicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(date) {
            parent.append($("<div class='editableDateTxt'/>").html(date));
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }).datepicker('show');
})
```

Comment: lo que muestra no tiene nada de lo que has intentado para guardarlo en una tabla dinamica...